# Create a direct connection between client pc and remote frp server

Tags: asp.net, http, ftp, file-transfer

Good day to everyone..

I'm devoloping an Asp.Net Web Application in which I have to implement file upload, but with a little complication:

To better explain, the application is running on server "A".. the files need to be uploaded to a completely distinct server "B"..

Once the client "C" uploads a file through the site interface, the file must actually be uploaded to server B.

Technically I already achieved this:

- client choses the file he wants to upload from his pc, then click "upload"
- during the postBack of the page", the server upoloads the file without saving it
- I pick up the fileStream from the FileUploas control and send it via ftp to server "B";

BUT, by doing this, actually the file is transferred twice (C -> A -> B), making the user experience of the file upload longer than normal..

My question is: is it possible to open a "direct" connection between "C" and "B" through the site interface (running on server "A"), in order to perform a single transfer? Obviously, I should be able to do the same thing during download..

An alternative (at least during upload) should be that of "hiding" the double transfer by saving a temp file on server "A", and then re-transfer it to "B" starting a separated task, so that the user will be able to perform new actions on the site after the "first" upload.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated (even quite different solutions, I'll then evaluate the "compatibility" with my project)

Thank you in advance,

Alberto

Note: I choose to go for FTP because the client must be able to select where he want the "B" server to be placed (he can use "our" ftp or, if he has one, send files there) and I think that FTP is the most "compatible" and "fast set up" solution, being ftp managed similarly independently to the server "B" platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear, what kind of connection you expect from C to be capable of making. If C can open direct connection to B, and if the server A has credentials for accessing B, the scenario can look as follows:

1. client C establishes command channel with server A
2. server A establishes command channel with server B
3. the client starts preparation for data transfer. At this point C requests passive mode from server A. A immediately starts preparation for data transfer with server B and requests passive mode from server B. This A-B preparation should take place completely between the server A receives PASV command from C and when it sends response to this command. So it should be *quick* (2-3 seconds max, I think).
4. Server A gets the address and port to connect to from server B and sends this data as a response to PASV command received from C.
5. C transfers the data to B. Server A receives "Transfer complete" from B via command channel and sends the same to the client.
6. Now server A can close command channel to server B (if needed).

The above requires that you know details of FTP protocol and most likely implement it yourself as both client and server. And this can be quite time-consuming.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thank you for answering.. I'm sorry for not being clear.. the fact is that I technically don't know how kind of connection should I use for connecting C to B, but I think the better opton is to use ftp.. In my set-up, the client is a simple browser that must use the asp.net application running in server "A", while "B" must be used in a "transparent" way as a file server..I'll give a look to PASV commands and Command Channels (I didn't even knew of their existance, but I'll try to remedy!!!)..
Thank you!

Comment: A clarification, to not spend my time in "unuseful" tasks (knowledge is always useful): is it possible to replicate the system you described in my case:
- server A is my ASP.net application, where I have full control
- C must be a common browser
- B must be a folder in a generic FTP server, where theorically I have no control except for knowing server name, username and password (if required)

Comment: @Alberto if C is just a browser, then the only thing I can think of is having B run a web server and directing the user there for upload (by opening a new page in a new tab/window). My greatly designed ;) scheme would not work in this case.

Comment: @alberto Welcome to SO. You can update your own question by editing it. You can vote for questions (upvote or downvote) and if you get the answer that satisfies your needs and answers your question, you can mark it as an answer

Comment: @Eugene thank you again.. I think that, at least for now, I'll implement the functonality "the simple way", with te double transfer, and in case "expand" the whole project and realize the great scheme you kindly designed for me! I'll mark the answer as a solution, even if it doesn't fit to my situation! Thank you!

Comment: A question.. what if I put in my web page a silverlight/flash/java applet, configured at runtime in order to pick up the current logged in user configuration, that then manage directly the file transfers from C to B and vice-versa and once operation is completed give a command to A?? This way the browser just need to have java/silverlight/flashplayer installed, which is quite common..

Comment: Browsers restrict plugin / applet access to third-party sites. I.e. from the web page, served from server A you would be able to connect oonly to server A, and if you make the browser take a page from server B (by opening a new page in browser), then on *that* page you can put an applet (taken from server B) which would be allowed to connect to server B.

Comment: Understood.. thank you again, one day or another I'll find a way out.. thank youvery much again!!